Class with deleted move assignment but with const copy assignment not move assignable
In the following test code, I understand why the class is still seen as move constructable, even though the default move constructor and assignment operator would not be implicitly generated by the compiler.
Understanding based on the following from cppreference.com:

Types without a move constructor, but with a copy constructor that accepts const T& arguments, satisfy std::is_move_constructible -- [Ref]

#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdbool>


struct DestructableMock {
    DestructableMock() : m_value(0x5a5a5a5a), m_output_debug(false) { }

    DestructableMock(unsigned int value) : m_value(value), m_output_debug(false) { }

    DestructableMock(unsigned int value, bool output_debug) : 
            m_value(value), m_output_debug(output_debug) {
    }
    
    ~DestructableMock() {
    }


    DestructableMock(const DestructableMock &src) {
        m_output_debug = src.m_output_debug;
        m_value = src.m_value;
    }

    //DestructableMock(DestructableMock &&src) = delete;

    DestructableMock& operator=(const DestructableMock &other) {
        if (&other != this) {
            m_value = other.m_value;
            m_output_debug = other.m_output_debug;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    unsigned int m_value;
    bool m_output_debug;
};

static_assert(!std::is_trivially_destructible_v<DestructableMock>);
static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<DestructableMock>);
// Types without a move constructor, but with a copy constructor that accepts const T& arguments,
// satisfy std::is_move_constructible.
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<DestructableMock>);
// But it is not trivially move constructable
static_assert(!std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<DestructableMock>);
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable_v<DestructableMock>);
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable_v<DestructableMock>);


int main() {
    return 0;
}

See code on programiz here
So, I can understand why static_assert(std::is_move_constructible_v<DestructableMock>); passes: there is no move constructor but there is a copy constructor accepting a const reference.
However, if I uncomment the line that explicitly deletes the move constructor, the same assertion fails. Why is this? There is still the "copy constructor that accepts const T& arguments", so why is it not seen as move constructable still?
My compiler version is gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 btw

Relevant Howard Hinnant's guideline: Never delete the special move members.


However, if I uncomment the line that explicitly deletes the move constructor, the same assertion fails. Why is this?

For deleted functions:

If the function is overloaded, overload resolution takes place first,
and the program is only ill-formed if the deleted function was
selected:

That means the explicitly deleted move constructor will be selected in overload resolution, then compilation fails as it's deleted.
For the 1st case, the class has only the copy constructor, then overload resolution selects it as it also accepts rvalues, everything is fine.

thanks for the answer! So when the move constructor/op can't be created implicitly by the compiler because I've defined the copy constructor/op then only the copy constructor/op will be considered. But, when the move constructor/op is explicitly deleted, it is considered... I guess my question becomes, why is it designed that way? Seems to my (naive?) mind a bit upside counterintuitive.

Ah, I found answer here: Ah I found answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/explicitly-defaulted-and-deleted-functions?view=msvc-170

The object is still considered moveable by is_move_constructible_v et al because the copy constructor accepting a const reference can accept an R-value. What still gets me is that, yes ok it can accept an R-value, but its not actually doing a move so is it really moveable. This leave me with the question, why was is_move_constructible defined this way? Why not make it only be true when there is a default or explicitly defined move constructor?

@Jimbo is_move_constructible is just defined as the object can be constructed from an rvalue, how it's constructed doesn't matter. It's constructed by a copy constructor, or a move constructor, and how the constructor is implemented, like if it's actually doing a "move", doesn't matter.

ah, that makes sense, thanks :)
